# How to open a tcp socket and process the continuous information obtained through it in Hazelcast Jet

Tags: hazelcast-jet

I am trying to analyze sensor data using Hazelcast jet.For that i need to open a Tcp socket and process the information obtained through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read from sockets in Jet using Socket streamer. Take a look at documentation: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/jet/0.4/manual/Vertices_in_the_Library/Sources.html#page_Socket+Streamer